# is it correct to say "today is rainy" or it is "today, it's rainy"?

Tags: sentence-construction, syntax

I was looking for an answer to another question and I've found an answer on the italki website, which makes unclear about which is the right usage.

Is it syntactically correct to say "today is rainy" or the right phrase is "today, it's rainy" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either is grammatically acceptable.

I would be more likely to use *"Today, it's rainy."* when I am comparing the weather on different days.

> What a crazy week.  Monday it was hot, with blue skies all day. Yesterday, it snowed.  **Today, it's rainy.**  [*Or* Today it's raining.]

The other form might be a little more likely for me if I am giving a comprehensive description of the current day.

> **Today is rainy.**  The wind is blowing, the leaves are falling, and I found my lost boots.  Today is the kind of day that makes me want to jump in mud puddles.

The difference between is very slight, however, and I would not recommend spending a whole lot of time deciding which to use - they are basically interchangeable.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on where you are writing this to be honest.

I think syntactically both would be fine in any informal context and I understand perfectly what you mean.

The reason is that in the first sentence, "today is rainy", today is the object being described directly, so you don't need the pronoun 'it'. In the second however, there is a comma so after the comma, the 'it' pronoun is needed to make the sentence correct (hence the 'it's').

However, while they are both acceptable, I wouldn't use either of these in a formal context, instead I would say "today was a rainy day" or "today it rained".

Answer (score 0):

When you emphasize the word *today*, then it's correct to say *"today, it's rainy."* However when you state a fact, then it's correct to say *"today is rainy."*

It depends on the context.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say second is correct, the first is technically incorrect.

In the sentence "Today it is rainy" it does not refer to today, but to the weather (implicitly). Though in normal speech it's not uncommon for the "it" part to be omitted because it's common knowledge what your talking about.

So in short today refers to a day, and a day can not be rainy (technically). Though it's common speech to refer to it as such, because everyone knows what your talking about anyway, so no problems omitting "it" :)